# HDF5 C++: write a string in a compound data set

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to save C++ data structures in HDF5 compound data set. Those data structures contains POD types and std::string. To handle std::string's correctly, for each structure `A`, I create a structure `CA` where I replace each `std::string`'s by a `const char*` pointer that will point to the memory hold by the `std::string` (return by the `c_str` methods).

Doing this leads to some strange results detailled below. I am using the HDF5 version `1.8.13` on a `debian Jessie`.

I tried to simplify my test to the bare minimal. Here is the code for writting a `H5::DataSet` (`r` is the root group of an HDF5 file):

```
//! a simple example of C-struct with a string
struct CString
{
  //! pointer to a C-string
  const char* value;
}; // end of struct CString
// compound description
H5::CompType c(sizeof(CString));
c.insertMember("value", HOFFSET(CString,value),H5::PredType::C_S1);
// value to be stored
std::string test = "my test value";
// place holder
CString ctest;
// not working: ctest.value= test.c_str()
ctest.value = strdup(test.c_str());
// data set creation
hsize_t dim[] = {1};
const auto d = r.createDataSet("test",c,DataSpace(1,dim));
d.write(&ctest,c);
```

The point is that I have to make a copy of the string to get the value in the HDF5 file. Otherwise, I get garbage.

Here is the code to read the value from the created file:

```
const auto f = File("test.hf5",H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
const auto r = f.getRoot();
// compound description
H5::CompType c(sizeof(CString));
c.insertMember("value", HOFFSET(CString,value),H5::PredType::C_S1);
// value to be read
CString test;
// reading
const auto d = r.openDataSet("test");
d.read(&test,c);
std::cout << test.value << std::endl;
```

(Here `File` is simple wrapper around the H5File class which provides the getRoot method)

With the copy a the string, the output is "my test value".
Without the copy a the string, the output is "A".

This behaviour seems inconsistent with various posts I read about writing/reading a std::string in HDF5. However, those posts never treated a compound dataset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the anwswer. I have to change the definition of the `value` member as follows:

```
H5::CompType c(sizeof(CString));
H5::StrType stype(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE);
c.insertMember("value", HOFFSET(CString,value),stype);
```

The fact that the example worked when copying the string is some sort of good fortune and has to do with the memory layout of my test.

Regards